# SideMenu Functionality in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4.1

I am setting up the side menu by following [SideMenu](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu)

When the app is loaded first the side menu controller is working fine (.menuslide)

but when I come back to the same controller from the side menu to the same view controller or any other controller or any other page it is not following (.menuslide)

1. I have tried by assigning the navigation

   ```
   let menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)
   let rightMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController) 
   SideMenuManager.default.rightMenuNavigationController = rightMenuNavigationController
   present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

through code and also

2. From the story board

   I am navigating from every controller to side menu like this

   ```
    let navigationController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sidemenunavigation") as! SideMenuNavigationController present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   ```

for the first time after loading it is navigating properly (.menuslide)

but after navigating to other controller and get the side menu it is not following (.menuslide)

Comment: Looks it ok, but that is not much helpful. If possible than share demo project, so people can find what exactly your mistake and fix issue.

Comment: Because your given third party link and someone integrate it proper, so it's waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

you may use the following RESideMenu for side menu quite easy to use
[RESideMenu for side menu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)

Comment: How to reflect .menuslide to all the pages  (View Controller)

Comment: But my Requirement is different need to follow

 https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

Comment: I did that one as describes in tutorial using segue. I got navigation controller nil so add a navigationController in the start I will give detailed answer in night

Answer (score 0):

please check this code is working fine for navigation another view controller for sidemenu

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil)
            if let conVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RoutingAddViewController") as? RoutingAddViewController,
               let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
                navController.pushViewController(conVC, animated: true)
            }
```